# Anti-causal systems

Tags: transfer-function

If Anti-causal systems are defined as those whose output depends solely upon future inputs.(Is this definition correct as I understand)

So i see that $y[n] = x[n+2]$ ; is anticausal system

How is a time reversing system such as:

$$y(t) = x(-t) $$

anticausal?

e.g. $y(2) = x(-2)$ it infact depends upon past.

Looking for some explanation.

Comment: i would call it "**acausal**" not "*anticausal*".

Answer (score 5):

$y(t) = x(-t)$ [is not anticausal, but it is acausal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticausal_system). For negative values of $t$, $y(t)$ is not causal, while for positive $t$, it is causal, since, for example, $y(2) = x(-2)$, but $y(-2) = x(2)$.

Comment: Thats what I thought, so this Wikipedia entry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_system needs correction then.

Comment: I would agree with you.

Comment: Yes, the Wikipedia entry is not correct. Note that Wikipedia says that _some_ authors distinguish between non-causal or acausal and anti-causal systems. My personal preference is to not join in this hair-splitting.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: It is not hair splitting, its plain incorrect,  Even if we go by the sentence on Wikipedia which you are referring to which says "Note that some authors have defined an anticausal system as one that depends solely on future and present input values or, more simply, as a system that does not depend on past input values"

Comment: What I meant by hairsplitting is that I prefer to not join the some authors in creating a subcategory of anticausal systems in the broadly defined set of noncausal systems. For those who do choose to define anticausal systems, we are in agreement that the Wikipedia example of $y(t) = x(-t)$ as a anti-causal system is plain incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

> If Anti-causal systems are defined as those whose output depends solely upon future inputs. (Is this definition correct as I understand)

How particular are you about the words *solely* and *future* in your definition?

A *causal* system is one with the property that the output $y$ at *every* 
time $t$ depends only on the current and past inputs, that is, 
the values of the input $x$ at times in $(-\infty, t]$, or more formally,

For each $t$, $-\infty < t < \infty$, 
$y(t)$ is a function of $\{x(\tau) \colon \tau \in (-\infty, t]\}$ only and 
does not depend on any $x(\tau^\prime), \tau^\prime > t$.

If *anticausal* is taken to mean *not causal*, then the complement of the
definition of causal
is *not* what you have written.  In this sense of "non-causal = not causal",

- a *non-causal* system is defined as one for which there is *at least one time 
  instant* $t_0$ (and a $\tau > t_0$) such that the output $y(t_0)$ depends on the 
  value of $x(\tau)$, a future input.

  - Note that $y(t_0)$ might depend on past inputs as well as on the future
    input $x(\tau)$.
  - Note that there may be other time instants $t_1$ for which $y(t_1)$ 
    depends only on past and curent $\{x(t) \colon t \in (-\infty, t_1]\}$
    and on *no* future inputs.  All it takes for a system to be bad-mouthed as
    non-causal is one bad apple time instant $t_0$ for which causality is violated.

On the other hand, *your* definition of *anti-causal* is that for *every* instant
$t$, $y(t)$ depends *solely* on *future* inputs 
$\{x(\tau) \colon \tau \in (t,\infty)\}$;
even the current input is excluded.  So, the time-reversal system 
$y(t) = x(-t)$ is *not* an anti-causal system by your definition.  Trivially,
$y(0)$ equals current input $x(0)$, and if you chill a bit and amend your
definition to say "current and future inputs", then, as Jason R has already
pointed out, $y(2)$ depends on a past input $x(-2)$ and so the system is
not anti-causal as per your amended definition either.  In fact, there
is a huge class of systems that would be classified as non-causal as per
the definition of non-causal given here that do not meet your definition
of anti-causality; the time-reversal system is just one example of
a system that is not anti-causal.

Answer (score 0):

Time reversal system is not "non-causal" or "not causal", rather it is not time invariant system. This may cause the confusion.